# Is it a valid step while solving modular arithmetic equation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

It's probably a very basic question. Is this equation $$91x\equiv21\pmod{56}$$
equivalent to $$35x\equiv21\pmod{56}$$
If so, then what property says that these equations are equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. You can write $91x=56x+35x$. Now since $56$ is zero mod $56$, this gives you that $91x=35x$.

Two numbers are the same modulo $56$ if their difference is an integer multiple of $56$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have
$$
91\equiv35\pmod{56}\quad\Rightarrow\quad91x\equiv35x\pmod{56}
$$
this seems to be simply a [Property of Equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_algebra#Properties_of_equality) or Equivalence.